# Android google play services not working properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

i just update google play services package, but its not working for me.Also i add

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to manifiset and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'` to build. gradle but its not working for me.

[image: import libraries]

Comment: try to use 10.0.1 latest version of play services.

Comment: What does "not working" mean. Please be specific with your error.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal thanx thats work for me

Comment: You only need maps and places library? Then only compile those https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @cricket_007 the appIndexing is under gms , seems like OP don't want the `Firebase App Indexing`  since app indexing import is `com.google.android.gms.appindexing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still using an old version of `PLAY Service` because `Places` was added in version `v.9.4` as mention in the official [**docs releases too**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

so simply update your `gms` dependencies to latest one i.e.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
```

You can also add individual API using appropriate version [as mention under Table 1 here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

So use individual API if you can because this will avoid the need of `Multudex` in future although there is no Individual APP INDEXING API `build.gradle` description mention  in the docs